# how to update the excel after receiving mail in python

Tags: python

I should update the excel  column as success after receiving the mail, I need a program for this in python

I need to update an excel sheet in particular column i should update it as success after receiving an mail

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First part: E-mails

Humberto Rocha has made a good explanation on his blog [here](https://humberto.io/blog/sending-and-receiving-emails-with-python/).
Check out the [chapter about receiving emails](https://humberto.io/blog/sending-and-receiving-emails-with-python/#receiving-emails) for your purposes. I will not go into depth with emails because I don't have any experience in this area.

Then, Excel:

As of now, you cannot edit Excel sheets directly with python.
What you can do instead is save the file as a CSV by going into Excel, going to "Save As", selecting the save directory and filename, and then in the save dialog, select "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)"
[image: This image describes the process way better than I]
Make sure to save the file in the same directory as your python script, and if you use the following code, save it as infile.csv.

Reading the CSV file with python would look like this:

```py
import csv
with open("infile.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ';')
    lines = list(reader)
```

That takes the CSV file named "infile.csv" and converts it into a list of Dictionaries, which is explained the best with an example. If your table looks like this:

country   capital
UK        London
Australia Sydney

Your list will look like this: [{'country': 'UK', 'capital': 'Sydney'},
{'country': 'Australia', 'capital': 'Sydney'}]
If you want to modify the list (like correcting the capital of Australia), you can do this by just writing

```py
lines[1]['capital'] = "Canberra"
```

(This is an example; I don't know how your Excel sheet looks. If you have any trouble figuring out how to do it, comment on this question and provide information about the structure of your Excel sheet.)

To save the file again, write:

```py
with open("outfile.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, lines[0].keys(), dialect='excel', delimiter=";")
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

You can then open the outcoming file (here outfile.csv) in Excel. If you want to convert it back to Excel, go to "Save File", select the folder and filename, and then save it as "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)" (or whatever format you want it to be in).